# How to create the sql server connection using c#

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I get strange error while getting the data from Sqlserver using c#.
 Actually i have develop an application in asp.net (c#) and i wrote the code to  get the from sqlserver database .It is working fine, but this work only when i log into system as Administrate.
When i login into my system as non-Administrate it is not working it throws connection failed exception .  Please help me how to resolve this error.

[image]

Actually my Connection string is :

```
        Data Source=OSBORNECHARLES2;Initial Catalog=TWO;Integrated Security=True;User ID=sa;Password=123
```

Comment: It would hep to know the exception that is being thrown. This would give more context to your question.

Comment: Hi thank you Rodney for your response, i have added the exception screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is because you have enabled "Integrated Security=True" set it to false. And try with a real sql server login.

Comment: Thank you Geethanga it is working fine now,but is it work to get data from net work server..?